# matplotlib syntax error while plotting the data

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to plot to visualize data using `matplotlib` but I am getting an error. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import datetime
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

data=open('final1.csv','r')
date&time,values = np.genfromtxt(data,delimiter=',',unpack=True,converters={0: mdates.bytespdate2num("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")})

plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.MaxNLocator(10))
plt.gca().xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter(('%d/%m/%Y %H:%M')))

plt.plot(date&time,values,color='red')

plt.ylabel('Values')
plt.xlabel('Date')

plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()

plt.show()
```

I am getting the following error:

```
date&time,values => np.genfromtxt(data,delimiter=',',unpack=True,converters=0:mdates.bytespdate2num("%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")})  
    ^ SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
```

my final.csv file looks like this:

```
3/1/2017 13:00,746.76
3/1/2017 13:30,760.98
3/1/2017 14:00,742.98
3/1/2017 14:30,720.48
3/1/2017 15:00,705.42
3/1/2017 15:30,738.12
3/1/2017 16:00,734.82
3/1/2017 16:30,712.74
3/1/2017 17:00,726.96
3/1/2017 17:30,721.14
3/1/2017 18:00,695.94
3/1/2017 18:30,676.5
```

Comment: Do you try to give a variable the name `date&time`? [`&` is a bitwise operator in Python.](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python3/python_basic_operators.htm)

Comment: `date&time` is not a valid identifier, remove the `&` (which is an operator).

Comment: @cdarke To call it datetime might also not be the best idea, when you import the module `datetime` :)

Comment: Good point @T !